# Android Does Runtime permission required for Internet and access network state in api 23 and above?

Tags: android

I am in bit of confusion.

Does Runtime permission required for Internet and access network state in api 23(marshmallow+) and above?

If yes please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: No, it doesn't It's normal permission. You need runtime permission only for dangerous permissions. You can check which permissions are dangerous [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous](here).

Comment: @ Vygintas B. Thank you. I need a clarification, you did it.

Comment: look this you got idea about all https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Answer (score 4):

No, only  privacy related permissions required runtime permissions.
checking INTERNET and network status is normal User permissions

Answer (score 3):

No you don't require run time permissions for INTERNET and NETWORK STATE.
For more details please check thie link

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Answer (score 3):

No, It's come under Normal Permissions, please check this

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html